# Persist Tooltip in Altair chart on click?

Tags: altair

I'd like to click on a point in a chart where a Tooltip pops up, but have the tooltip stay open until I click out of the tooltip.

```py
alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x=alt.X(f"{x}:T"),
    y=alt.Y(f"{y}:Q"),
    tooltip=[alt.Tooltip("Name:N"),
             alt.Tooltip("Symbol:N"),
             alt.Tooltip("Date NY:T"),
             alt.Tooltip("Close", format="$.2f")]
).properties(
  width=900
)
```

I looked over the documentation at https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.Tooltip.html but didn't find anything related to clicking on the tooltip.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to do that with the built-in tooltip, maybe requesting at https://github.com/vega/vega-tooltip would be worthwhile (that's the underlying library altair uses). You could create another chart using mark_text and have it activate the way you want.